# Automatic Reference Counting and the UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having a very strange issue with the UINavigationController in combination with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).
I've got this iPad application with a UIViewController that contains a view with some subviews.
It's view has a UIScrollView in it( with at least 5 subviews), and 2 simple views, a black bar and a white bar.

Whenever I push something on the UINavigationController stack, let's say a WebView, and I get a memory warning, the UINavigationController calls ViewDidLoad on all current, and previous UIViewControllers that were/are on it's stack.

Now comes the problem, when I pop said WebView from the stack, and I return to the UIViewController with the scrollview, it's gone!
It's completely blanked out.

I suspect the -didReceiveMemoryWarning method deallocs some things under the hood since ARC is enabled. How can I force ARC to keep hold on to this specific ViewController?

Can someone please help me with this? Because it's really annoying me at this very moment.

Thanks a lot!

-B

Comment: How are you creating the contents of the scroll view? It's perfectly normal for them to be deleted when you load up something like a web view, and depending how they were created, they might not automatically be re-created when you go back to the view. This doesn't have anything to do with ARC, it's just how memory management works on iOS (if a low memory warning occurs and you don't free up some memory, your app will crash instead). You can test it using "Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning" in the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're loading something very heavy in your web view that causes a memory warning (or you're doing other things that lead to a low memory conditions). UINavigationController receives `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` and forwards it to all view controllers who unload their views (-> `viewDidUnload`tells you to release things you don't want to stay in memory. ARC does not cover this so you have to nil out everything that is view-related).
When you go back, `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` are called. You probably don't completely restore your views - especially your scroll view - to match the state they were in before the memory warning.

Keep in mind that in iOS 5 memory warnings occur less often than in previous iOS versions (the OS tries to free as much memory as possible for you) but when you receive a memory warning, that is your last chance to stay alive.

Comment: The memory intensive stuff happens in the scrollview, it's mostly loaded with 5 subviews containing rather large background images, for great visual content. The iPad 2 covers this perfectly, this bug only occurs on the iPad 1. So I'll beed to restore the scrollview whenever I pop back, and that should be done in the viewDidLoad method i reckon?

Comment: I've done the above mentioned thing and it seems to work. Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: large background images can be dangerous.. (especially JPG images). when you want to zoom you can use CATiledLayer to lazy load different zoom levels. and you should not have more than 2 active CATiledLayer / UIImageView objects in your topmost scroll view - maybe you should consider reusing views (like UITableView does for cells) to save memory.

Comment: WWDC 2010 video on advanced scrollview techniques covers both :)

Comment: They're PNG files, and I'm not zooming so the Tiled stuff is kind-off obsolete for my case. But I've had another question regarding this bug: what is best practice for low  memory warnings? removing all subviews and setting them nil in the didReceiveMemoryWarning, and just setting them to nil in the viewDidUnload, or.. something else?

Comment: there are a lot of things you can do. you should release all subview in `viewdidUnload`, release all model objects you don't need or cache them to disk. then there are a lot of things you can to to avoid low memory conditions in first place.. (don't retain UIImage objects, use databases for storage and don't retain the model classes if not needed, download images / web content to disk and not to memory, ...)

Comment: Well, I'm using ARC, so I'm not in control of the retains you mentioned... I'm stuck here. I really think I'm not going to use ARC anymore. I want to be in direct control of everything...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4915/discussion-between-bryan-and-martin-ullrich)